# Executing JavaScript within <body> on div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to setup a small 'feedback' text-box that cycles through an array of quotes, along with the names of the sources of the quotes.

My code is as follows:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    ...
    <div id="testimonial_text">One</div>
    <div id="testimonial_name">1</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            cycleText();
            cycleName();
        }); 

        function cycleText() {
            var text = ['One','Two','Three'],
                i = 1,
                $div = $('#testimonial_text');

            setInterval(function() {
                $div.fadeOut(function () {
                    $div.text(text[i++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
                });
            }, 1000);
        }

        function cycleName() {
            var text = ['1','2','3'],
                j = 1,
                $div = $('#testimonial_name');

            setInterval(function() {
                $div.fadeOut(function () {
                    $div.text(text[j++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    </script>
    ...
</body>
```

Things that I have tried and that have not worked:

Replacing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

with

```
<script>
```

&

Replacing

```
$(function () {
    cycleText();
    cycleName();
});
```

with

```
window.onload=function() {
    cycleText();
    cycleName();  
}
```

or

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    cycleText();
    cycleName();
});
```

I know it would be more ideal to contain all of the JS within the head tags, but this is not possible with the way that the website is setup.

Please note that I have a jsfiddle set-up that works perfectly here: https://jsfiddle.net/3ke2esht/3/

However, it doesn't work on the live webpage here: 
REMOVED LINK POST-ANSWER

Can anyone tell me why this might be the case, and how I could potentially fix this?

EDIT: I can make it work if I remove the following code from my head:

```
<!-- optional touchswipe file to enable swipping to navigate slideshow -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="head/slideshow/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="head/slideshow/fadeslideshow.js">

/***********************************************
* Ultimate Fade In Slideshow v2.0- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* Please keep this notice intact
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more
***********************************************/

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var gallery=new fadeSlideShow({
    wrapperid: "slideshow", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
    dimensions: [900, 350], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
    imagearray: [
        ["head/slideshow/1.jpg"],
        ["head/slideshow/2.jpg"],
        ["head/slideshow/3.jpg"],
        ["head/slideshow/4.jpg"]
    ],
    displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:6500, cycles:0, wraparound:true},
    persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
    fadeduration: 750, //transition duration (milliseconds)
    descreveal: "always",
    togglerid: ""
})

</script>
```

Which was taken/modified slightly from dynamicdrive.com.

Obviously I want both scripts to be working. Something from this is preventing the first one from working, but I can't see what!

Comment: What is your question exactly?  You have a working fiddle, so what's the issue?  And why can't you add js to the <script> tags?

Comment: @jmargolisvt Sorry, I meant I can't add JS within the head tags. And I've just appended the original post with a question. It works in the fiddle, but not on the live web-page (which I've linked).

Comment: Updated the post with some more information that could help to solve the problem. If I remove some code from my head then I can make it work. The problem is that I don't want to have to do that!

Comment: You appear to be missing the closing `</html>` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an error message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

Which means the variable `$` isn't correctly associated with the jQuery library. You may be using another library that's taking over the `$` or calling `jQuery.noConflict()`. In your case, the file `fadeslideshow.js` is calling `noConflict()`, as noted by @Phil.

The safest solution would be to replace all references to `jQuery`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        cycleText();
        cycleName();
    }); 

    function cycleText() {
        var text = ['One','Two','Three'],
            i = 1,
            $div = jQuery('#testimonial_text');

        setInterval(function() {
            $div.fadeOut(function () {
                $div.text(text[i++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    function cycleName() {
        var text = ['1','2','3'],
            j = 1,
            $div = jQuery('#testimonial_name');

        setInterval(function() {
            $div.fadeOut(function () {
                $div.text(text[j++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Also, you can create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), which takes as parameter the correct reference to `jQuery` and put your code inside it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(function () {
            cycleText();
            cycleName();
        }); 

        function cycleText() {
            var text = ['One','Two','Three'],
                i = 1,
                $div = $('#testimonial_text');

            setInterval(function() {
                $div.fadeOut(function () {
                    $div.text(text[i++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
                });
            }, 1000);
        }

        function cycleName() {
            var text = ['1','2','3'],
                j = 1,
                $div = $('#testimonial_name');

            setInterval(function() {
                $div.fadeOut(function () {
                    $div.text(text[j++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

This way you can correctly use the `$` symbol as a reference to jQuery.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I have commented out the noConflict() line and it doesn't seem like it was needed. I'll keep your other points in mind for the future!