# $ is undefined SignalR Javascript Client

Tags: javascript, signalr

I create a javascript Signalr Client, but I debug in Firefox, it shows "$ is undefined".

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>SignalR Client</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:8080');
        var hub = connection.ChatHub;

        $.connection.hub
        .start()
        .done(function () {
            $('#send').click(function () {
                hub.server.hello();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="send">Say Hello!</button>
<p id="message"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have searched some topics like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179644/signalr-connection-is-undefined) but it's not working.

I also created a console application and it connected to my HubServer.

The reference is like this image below.

[image]

Comment: When you look in the Scripts tab, do you see it successfully loading `jquery-1.8.2.js`?

Comment: Where is Scripts tab?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing JavaScript within <body> on div elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449114/executing-javascript-within-body-on-div-elements). See the accepted answer

Comment: @ANguyen Sorry, I meant the Sources list in the Debugger tab of the web console.

Comment: @Barmar it displays "This page has no sources"

Comment: Did you load the page first? I only see that when I open the web console on a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

This means that jQuery is not being included, you may load it from Google or jQuerys own CDN if you local link is not good.

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be in *noConflict* mode (see the duplicate link above)

Comment: Yea, if the path is wrong or maybe you have that file blocked or something then jQuery can't load and you get a $ is not defined, also see what Phill said about the noConflict mode